# Problem installing Lizmap web client

Tags: qgis, web-service, lizmap

I'm trying to install lizmap web client, following the steps present in here: http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/11/06/Test-LizMap-on-Windows-with-OSGEO4W.
But unfourtunally i can't get by step 20, this because when i install OSGeo4W it does not create the temp folder that is necessary to store lizmap temporare files.
Can anyome help?
Sorry for the english, i'm portuguese.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a directory called tmp directly under the OSGeo4W catalog and try again.